# Make an Item Visible on Scrolling the Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

**CSS:** `.top-items { position: fixed; right: 0; top: 0; z-index: 99; margin: 6px; } .top-item { background: #000; color: #fff; border-radius: 6px; padding-left: 7px; padding-right: 7px; padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 1px; font-size: 13px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); -webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08); -moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08); -o-text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08); text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08); }`

**HTML:** `<div class="top-items"><a href="#"><span class="top-item">Log In</span></a><a href="#"><span class="top-item">Register</span></a></div>`

This is the design of two links of Log In & Register in my site! The position of these items are fixed at the top & in the right. There are some other items in the Navbar & these links are making touch issues for them.

So I want to modify it. It should be visible, on scrolling the screen to the bottom, after the few Pixels of Navbar crosses.

Please share me the JavaScript/jQuery of it.

Comment: until the few pixels of Navbar crosses?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it.

Comment: Show your jQuery Code, whatever you are using Or Use it `window.scroll(0, 0);`